# Cannot connect to Remote Management with Screen Sharing, but can with Chicken?

Tags: remote-desktop

I've enabled "remote management" on a machine, and I'm able to connect to this machine using Chicken with the password I set in the remote management preference pane. I am unable to connect through the "Screen Sharing" app however, which I access by pressing <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> in the finder. The Screen Sharing app requests a username and a password, so it does appear that it's at least connecting at that level, but neither my account username/password nor the password I set specifically for remote management work. Since Chicken doesn't require a username I'm not sure what username I should use!

Does anyone know how to connect to Remote Management through the Screen Sharing app?

Edit: I should add that the RealVNC viewer also works.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD No worries, I see you deleted your comments so I deleted my replies.

Comment: I think the "Chicken" confused me. That is the "Chicken of the VNC" which is a VNC client for Mac OS X.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD That was its old name, it is now known as just "Chicken" http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/